# Manipulate three arrays

Tags: javascript

The goal of the exercice is to manipulate 3 arrays.

```
tabName = new Array('Chaton', 'Aigle', 'Bison', 'Blaireau');
tabAdjective = new Array('PETEUR', 'BIGLEUX', 'CRETIN', 'MALIN');
tabLetters = new Array('a','b','c','d');
```

When the user enters (on html) a first name and a name (between a and d) in html it retrieves the character of the array tabName and tabLetters.

Example the user enters as first name **amelia** and name it enters **bael**
the result will be Chaton Bigleux

How recuperate the index from tableName ? 
Here is my code (for now)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  tabName = new Array('Chaton', 'Aigle', 'Bison', 'Blaireau');
  tabAdjective = new Array('PETEUR', 'BIGLEUX', 'CRETIN', 'MALIN');
  tabLetters = new Array('a','b','c','d');

  function main()
  {
    first_name = save_first_name.value;
    //alert(first_name);
    first_name_character = first_name.charAt(0);

    i = 0;
    while(first_name_character != tabLetters)
    {

        tmp = tabName[i];
        i++;

    }


  }


  </script>


  <body>
    <center>
     <h2><ul>Exercice 01</ul></h2>
     First Name : <input type="text" id="save_first_name" size="15">
     Name :     <input type="text" id="save_name" size="15">
                <input type="submit" value="ok" onclick="main()">
                <input type="text" id="result" size="25">
     </center>
  </body>

  </head>
 </html>
```

Comment: Because this is an exercise, i will start with just a hint: to easily know at which index is an element in an array, you can use `myArray.indexOf(elementToSearch)`. This can be used to find where are the indexes where the name first letter can be found in `tabLetters`

Comment: If you don't have to use an array then you can use an object like e.g. `tabName = { a: 'Chaton', b: 'Aigle', c: 'Bison', d: 'Blaireau' };` and can easily lookup the name by doing `tabName[first_name.charAt(0)]`

Comment: @ Kaddath; I don't understand, :-(

Comment: @ apokryfos: I must use only arrays  :-(

Comment: i'll explain by exemple: with your array `tabLetters = new Array('a','b','c','d');`, if i want to search where i can find `'a'` in the array, using `var index = tabLetters.indexOf('a');` will give `0` for `index` (which is where you can find your element in the array, `tabLetters[0] == 'a'` here)

Comment: @ Kaddath my problem is now resolve thank :-)